# ACPI STORE location depending on parameter

Tags: acpi

I'm trying to store the value of `\_SB.I2C1.(value passed as parameter)` into `BUFF`. This code doesn't work, but is there any mechanism within ASL that will allow me to do this?

```
CreateByteField(BUFF, 0x02, DATA)
Name(REGO, 0x0)
Method(DI2C, 1)
{
         Store(Arg0, REGO)
         Store (\_SB.I2C1.REGO, BUFF)
}
```